# MSAccess query between two time fields when adding fields together works fine when subtracting gives error

Tags: ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

I have two fields on a query MinOfClocked_Time and MaxOfClocked_Time, When adding the two with the following code

```
TimeWorked: [MaxOfClocked_Time]+[MinOfClocked_Time]
```

and i get a result of 07:0207:02, But if I Subtract them

```
TimeWorked: [MaxOfClocked_Time]-[MinOfClocked_Time]
```

then i get #Error, So i now the format is correct but not subtracting the two fields. Can any please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, when you subtract one time from another you are actually subtracting two numbers.

see the [negative date is not possible in ms access](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/display-negative-time-in-ms-access-2010/985c5071-c11a-4986-aa78-5073c3de2034).

and use [Datediff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/datediff-function-access-custom-web-app) instead.

Answer (score 0):

TimeWorked:=([MaxOfClocked_Time]-[MinOfClocked_Time])*24

Try that.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error, because your "times" are stored as text.

```vb
[MaxOfClocked_Time] = "07:02"
[MinOfClocked_Time] = "07:02"

' Concatenate the text times:
? [MaxOfClocked_Time]+[MinOfClocked_Time]
07:0207:02

' Cannot "subtract" text:
? [MaxOfClocked_Time]-[MinOfClocked_Time]
#Error
```

However, true time values can easily be added or subtracted, say:

```vb
' Text:
[MaxOfClocked_Time] = "14:27"
[MinOfClocked_Time] = "09:42"

' Date:
MaxTime = CDate([MaxOfClocked_Time])
MinTime = CDate([MinOfClocked_Time])

? MaxTime - MinTime
 0.197916666666667

? CDate(MaxTime - MinTime)
04:45:00

' However, a negative value will not be shown when converted to Date:

? MinTime - MaxTime
-0.197916666666667

? CDate(MinTime - MaxTime)
04:45:00
```

To display a negative time, use *Format*:

```vb
Format(MaxTime - MinTime, ";-") & Format(MaxTime - MinTime, "hh:nn")
04:45

Format(MinTime - MaxTime, ";-") & Format(MinTime - MaxTime, "hh:nn")
-04:45
```

This, of course, only works as intended when the time span is within 24 hours.

If 24 hours or more, use a custom function like this:

```vb
Public Function FormatHourMinuteDiff( _
  ByVal datTimeStart As Date, _
  ByVal datTimeEnd As Date, _
  Optional ByVal strSeparator As String = ":") _
  As String
  
' Returns count of days, hours and minutes of difference
' between datTimeStart and datTimeEnd converted to
' hours and minutes as a signed formatted string
' with an optional choice of time separator.
'
' Example:
'   datTimeStart: #10:03#
'   datTimeEnd  : #20:01#
'   returns     : 9:58
'
'   datTimeStart: #22:13#
'   datTimeEnd  : #3:45#
'   returns     : -18:28
'
' 2005-02-05. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
  
  Const cintMinutesHour As Integer = 60
  
  Dim lngMinutes    As Long
  Dim strHour       As String
  Dim strMinute     As String
  Dim strHourMinute As String
  
  lngMinutes = DateDiff("n", datTimeStart, datTimeEnd)
  strHour = CStr(lngMinutes \ cintMinutesHour)
  ' Add leading zero to minute count when needed.
  strMinute = Right("0" & CStr(Abs(lngMinutes) Mod cintMinutesHour), 2)
  strHourMinute = strHour & strSeparator & strMinute
  
  FormatHourMinuteDiff = strHourMinute
  
End Function
```